# How I will limit the creation of account?

Tags: android

I want to do a car wash application and view it to many car wash company. If they love it a will give them a tablet with the application.

In the programming: how I will make each company to sign up once ?? Should I give them the username and password and cancel the sign up button so they can’t get more than one account, or is there another option so I can limit the company from creating more than one account!!

Comment: I think you should give them a username or password. If you want to stop fake car wash user.

Comment: Please always try to ask something related to code. You can easily achieve this by setting unique attribute for username of USER table. Then it does not allow duplicate username.

Answer (score -1):

This should be depend on, where you are going to implement your application. If you are planning to implement it on huge number of car wash companies, it should not be a feasible way.
`email id` for every car wash company should be consider as an `unique constraint`. you can check the email id is already existing or not while `SignUp` and can verify the user.

Comment: What's your motivation behind making the phone number a unique constraint for a company?

Comment: What about if they use another email to register?

Comment: if you are planning to give a tablet to them, then you can also check the `IMEI` id along with email.